# Service Fabric - The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure-service-fabric

When I am trying to open an sql connection using normal application have no issues. But when I tried with stateless service fabric application, I got the following error "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."

I used the following connection string to connect to my DB:

When I tried with a specific username and password, its working fine. How to run the service fabric application against a specific user account as we normally did in our windows application?

Thnaks,
Divya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Service Fabric Service is running as the 'NETWORK SERVICE' by default. This account is a local account, unlikely to be allowed access to SQL Server.

You can [change the account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security) you run your Service under. (chapter 'Use an Active Directory domain group or user')

Keep in mind that you should be running with least privileges, so I'd recommend creating a separate account that can only access the database it needs to. (no other db's, no other servers, etc.)

You can also [grant the NETWORK SERVICE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx) account of each cluster node access to the database.

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much. When I added the '<SecurityAccessPolicies>
    <SecurityAccessPolicy ResourceRef="MyCert" PrincipalRef="TestUser" GrantRights="Full" ResourceType="Certificate" />
  </SecurityAccessPolicies>' in the manifest file, I couldn't deploy the application. I commented only that part and now its workin.

Comment: I am facing another issue. I am using application insights for logging information.  Some of the assemblies which is referring to my application is writing logs to the event viewer directly. But after applying the aboce change, its throwing exception "Cannot open log for source 'Application'. You may not have write access". I have updated the application manifest file to include the SecurityAccessPolicies section and the correct certificate. And also provide full right permission to eventviewer for all users. Still it has the same problem